# FFmpeg RTP network issue in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, network-programming, video-streaming, rtp

I want to copy a bunch of SD sources from mpegts transported with RTP on local files. (VBR mpeg2video, mp2 audio). It works fine for one multicast source with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtp://@IP1:PORT -c copy video1.mpg
```

but when I ran a second ffmpeg instance with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtp://@IP2:PORT -c copy video2.mpg
```

then I got errors from both FFmpeg instances *("RTP: dropping old packet received too late")* and in both files (video1.mpg and video2.mpg) recorded video from the second source (rtp://@IP2:PORT).

This issue occurs only in Linux (I checked Ubuntu 14.04 - 16.04). I have no problems in Windows and can transcoding video correctly in parallel from files. Under Ubuntu even two ffplay instances tuned to different sources play back the same content (from the source which was opened last). I tried playing back with VLC and there is no such problem.

I can resolve this issue when using FFmpeg with the -f option: 
ffmpeg **-f mpegts** -i rtp://@IP1:PORT -c copy video1.mpg 
 and 
ffmpeg **-f mpegts** -i rtp://@IP2:PORT -c copy video2.mpg, but then I'm getting the following errors: *"[mpegts @ 0x306e240] PES packet size mismatch"* and receive both files (video1.mpg and video2.mpg) with artifacts and freeze effects. This issue appears for both operating systems.

**How can I record|transcode videos from multiple RTP streams with FFmpeg simultaneously under Ubuntu without errors and artifacts?**

Comment: Did you solve your problem?! I got RTP packet loss, and picture missing errors.

Comment: Using udp to http proxy (udpxy) solved this issue for me.

Comment: I want to run ffmpeg in android, so I guess I can't use udpxy solution. Do you agree Increasing Max UDP buffer size can help?

Comment: In my case it has not helped.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

If using a multicast group you may need to set the `sources` parameter to receive packets sent from the specified address.

> **sources=address[,address]**
>
> Only receive packets sent to the multicast group from one of the specified sender IP addresses.

`ffmpeg -i rtp://[multicast-address]:port?sources=xxx`

---

This is most likely caused by an [undersized receive buffer](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/jgroups-perf-udpbuffer.html) on your Linux machine. Since you mentioned SD it must be set pretty low.

You can get the current value in bytes with:

`sysctl net.core.rmem_max`

and set a new value with:

`sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=26214400`

or edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm set net.core.rmem_max to 26214400. net.core.rmem_max value was 212992. Also tried to change net.core.rmem_default value, unfortunately it's not help.

Comment: If two `ffplay` commands with 2 different sources play the same thing maybe there's something wrong with your multicast. What's transmitting on the other end?

Comment: I'm using following commands:
ffplay -i rtp://IP1:PORT?sources=SourceIP1 - everything is fine.
Then:
ffplay -i rtp://IP2:PORT?sources=SourceIP2 - in both windows is playing video from rtp://IP2:PORT. When I closed second ffplay instance in the first window again playing video from rtp://IP1:PORT.
But I can playing two different video streams(rtp://IP1:PORT and rtp://IP2:PORT) via VLC in Ubuntu.

Comment: In Addition: When I open two ffplay instance with different url (rtp://IP1:PORT?sources=SourceIP1 and rtp://IP2:PORT?sources=SourceIP2) they playing the same video from rtp://IP2:PORT. In that moment I open url (rtp://IP1:PORT?sources=SourceIP1) in VLC and VLC is playing video from rtp://IP1:PORT.

Comment: @aergistal Do you have any idea where is this file in Android Source code?! (before compiling AOSP, there is no output folder that contains etc folder; I want to change sysctl.conf before compile)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution, but can resolve this issue. 
I run [udpxy](http://www.udpxy.com/index-en.html) as follow: `udpxy -p 5556` 
Then run ffmpeg in the following way: `ffmpeg -i http://0.0.0.0:5556/rtp/239.255.1.1:5044`