# Why can't receive the rtp stream from another pc in the same network?

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtp

I am streaming the desktop over rtp using ffmpeg from computer A. Here is my ffmpeg code:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 25 -video_size 1920x1080 -i :1.0 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -pix_fmt bgr0 -b:v 3M -g 25 -an -f rtp_mpegts rtp://230.0.0.1:5005
```

I can play the live stream in vlc in the computer A in "rtp://@230.0.0.1:5005". But I can't play the stream from computer B that is in the same network with computer A. If I stream an mp4 file over http, than computer B is able to play it. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is alright until I tried windows version. A compromise solution, using a port forward software.

I used AUTAPF to forward local port to remote devices port on A, luckily it  worked for me.

`127.0.0.1:1234 -->  192.168.1.101:1234`

Be careful, `192.168.1.101:1234` belongs to the receiver `B`.

then play stream on remote computer `B` with `192.168.1.101:1234`

Another example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36148931/9455130